# boost asio unix socket reuse

Tags: c++, networking, boost, boost-asio, unix-socket

I want to use "each io_service per worker thread" design in my program. But I cant reuse unix socket:

```
io_service io_1;
io_service io_2;
::unlink("/tmp/test");
stream_protocol::endpoint ep("/tmp/test");
stream_protocol::acceptor acceptor_1(io_1, ep, true);
stream_protocol::acceptor acceptor_2(io_2, ep, true);
io_1.run();
io_2.run();
```

fails with "address already in use". When I open my asio/basic_socket_acceptor.hpp (boost 1.46.1) I see description to acceptor's constructor:

This constructor creates an acceptor and automatically opens it to listen for new connections on the specified endpoint.

@param reuse_addr whether the constructor should set the socket option socket_base::reuse_address.

```
basic_socket_acceptor(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, 
    const endpoint_type& endpoint, bool reuse_addr = true)
```

This a boost asio bug and I should send it to the bugtracker, am I right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you should use 1 acceptor on one of the threads. Instead you created two acceptors.

So you need to run 1 acceptor and spread different connection sessions on different `io_service`s.

Note:

```
io_1.run();
io_2.run();
```

Does not run any thread...

Re-Read the examples and try to understand them

Comment: thanks! realy only one acceptor. I found a good example http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/server2/server.cpp

Comment: it is normal that my example does not run any thread: exception was thrown in second contructor and I solved not to clutter up a question. thanks